# Problem setting the range of non continuous range in vba access manipulating excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am creating a Excel sheet from Access and I need to format the sheet from Access VBA, but when I try this piece of code it returns a error 1004:

```
Set rng = .Range("A2:E" & LastRow & "," & "J2:M" & LastRow)
With rng
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
End With
```

If I try it for each range it works:

```
Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
```

I have this very same piece of code on a Excel spreadsheet and it works like a charm, but maybe from Access I should use another syntax:

```
With DestWB.Sheets(strSheetName)
  .Range("B2:B" & MyLastRow - 3 & "," & "D2:D" & MyLastRow - 3 & "," & "H2:H" & MyLastRow - 3 & "," & "I2:I" & MyLastRow - 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
```

Can someone point me how to apply the formatting to non continuous ranges on similar to this one?

Comment: What operations you're trying to do with that "rng" variable? some operations are not available for combined (area) range i.e. rng.cut etc. So in this case you can do different ranges variable as @mdelapena suggested

Comment: Simple thing:  With rng
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
    End With

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with more of your code?

Comment: `Intersect` might be useful here.

Comment: I have included my code on the question as you asked BigBen.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's because you are assigning 2 ranges to a single range. you can either give 2 cell objects as parameters or a single string (just like in your working example).

I don't know what you are trying to do, but I would suggest to assign those 2 `Ranges` to 2 different variables, and then use those variables separately.

```
Set rng1 = .Range("A2:E" & LastRow)
Set rng2 = .Range("J2:M" & LastRow)
```

click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) for more on how to use the `Range` object.

Comment: Thanks but that´s what I am trying to avoid. I made something similar on a spreadsheet directly on Excel´s VBA and it worked and I can´t replicate it in Access VBA: .Range("B2:B" & MyLastRow - 3 & "," & "D2:D" & MyLastRow - 3 & "," & "H2:H" & MyLastRow - 3 & "," & "I2:I" & MyLastRow - 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Comment: I would try to avoid that, it can get confusing. But if you really need to refer to multiple ranges at once try joining the ranges with `Union()`, like this: `Set myRanges = Union(rng1, rng2)`